# Remove newlines from MarkupBuilder result

Tags: groovy, markupbuilder

Is there a way to control groovy's MarkupBuilder's output and filter out the newline characters? I have code like below:

```
import groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder

def writer = new StringWriter()
def xml = new MarkupBuilder(writer)
xml.basket(){
    fruit (type:"apple", 1)
    fruit (type:"orange", 2)    
}
```

which invariably outputs:

```
<basket>
  <fruit type='apple'>1</fruit>
  <fruit type='orange'>2</fruit>
</basket>
```

I'd really like it in a single line:

```
<basket><fruit type='apple'>1</fruit><fruit type='orange'>2</fruit></basket>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with StreamingMarkupBuilder:

```
import groovy.xml.StreamingMarkupBuilder

def xml = new StreamingMarkupBuilder().bind {
  basket(){
    fruit (type:"apple", 1)
    fruit (type:"orange", 2)    
  }
}
println xml.toString()
```

That prints out

```
<basket><fruit type='apple'>1</fruit><fruit type='orange'>2</fruit></basket>
```